# Proyecto en Visual estudio me da error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Muy buenas noches, me gustaría saber cual es el problema que me esta generando el error de NotImplementedException
 tengo mi formulario y cuando presiono el botón consultar no hay problema, cuando ingreso el código de proveedor me genera el problema, este es el código del botón consultar.

```
namespace FacturacionCompras
{
    public partial class Formulario_web11 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnConsultar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TextPROVEEDOR.Text == "")
            {
                lblMensaje.Text = "Debe de ingresar un cod de proveedor";
                TextPROVEEDOR.Focus();
                return;
            }
            if (!CADFacturacion.CADProveedor.ExisteProveedor(TextPROVEEDOR.Text))
            {
                lblMensaje.Text = "Proveedor no existe";
                TextPROVEEDOR.Focus();
                return;
            }
            CADFacturacion.DSFacturacion.PROVEEDORDataTable miProveedor = CADFacturacion.CADProveedor.GetProveedor(TextPROVEEDOR.Text);
            foreach (DataRow row in miProveedor.Rows)
            {
                TextNOMBRE.Text = row["NOM PROV"].ToString();
                TextDIRECCION.Text = row["Direccion"].ToString();
                TextPAIS.Text = row["pais"].ToString();
                CalFecha.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row["Fecha"]);
            }

            lblMensaje.Text = "Proveedor Consultado";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: solo eso obtienes un NotImplementedException ? no dice nada la propiedad Message del exception que aporte algun otro dato sobre el problema

Comment: NotImplementedException Es una excepción que por lo general se lanza cuando una clase se construye automaticamente, y uno (o varios) de los metodos deben ser implementados. 

O sea, por lo general, tu no escribiste esta excepción, si no que esta en alguna parte de tu codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías poner más información, como por ejemplo la definición de cada método, sin embargo aquí va mi apuesta.

Como tú dices, si haces click sin introducir nada funciona, esto es porque entra en la primera parte de la condición.

```
if (TextPROVEEDOR.Text == "")
{
   lblMensaje.Text = "Debe de ingresar un cod de proveedor";
   TextPROVEEDOR.Focus();
   return;
}
```

Es decir, muestras un error y sales del método.

Sin embargo si esa condición no se cumple pasas a la siguiente, es aquí uno de los posibles casos donde puede fallar:

```
CADFacturacion.CADProveedor.ExisteProveedor(TextPROVEEDOR.Text)
```

Si se muestra el error de que el proveedor no existe entonces es que ese método funciona correctamente y por consecuencia el que no está implementado es :

```
CADFacturacion.CADProveedor.GetProveedor(TextPROVEEDOR.Text);
```

Comprueba o enseña la definición de ambos si quieres que sea más preciso. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace CADFacturacion
{
    internal class CADProveedor
    {
        internal static DSFacturacion.PROVEEDORDataTable GetProveedor(string text)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        internal static bool ExisteProveedor(string text)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

este es el otro código, creo que el error esta en ese namespace.

```
 using CADFacturacion;
    using CADFacturacion.DSFacturacionTableAdapters;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace CADProveedor

    {
        public class CADProveedor
        {
            private static PROVEEDORTableAdapter adapter = new PROVEEDORTableAdapter();
            public static DSFacturacion.PROVEEDORDataTable GetProveedor(string COD_PROV)
            {
                return adapter.GetProveedor(COD_PROV);
            }
            public static bool ExisteProveedor(string COD_PROV)
            {
                return adapter.ExisteProveedor(COD_PROV) == 1;
            }
        }
    }
```